# Qt get mouse pressed event without focus

Tags: qt, background, focus, mouse, symbian

How can I get the location of where the mouse was pressed from an application running in the background (so it doesn't have focus)? I do not want to grab the mouse from all other apps I just want to know where it is pressed because I want it to react to the mouse being pressed on a certain position no matter what app is currently active and in focus?

I have tried creation a QWidget like this:

```
#ifndef MOUSECLICK_H
#define MOUSECLICK_H

#include "QWidget"
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QDebug>

class mouseClick : public QWidget
{
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
    {
        QPoint position = event->pos();
        qDebug() << position.x();
        printf("%d %d,positon.x,position.y");
    }
};

#endif // MOUSECLICK_H
```

And then I just used its show() function from main, but it doesn't respond once another app becomes active and in focus.

If it makes a difference this is for Symbian(Belle).

I think an event filter might be the answer but I have no idea how to configure it to intercept events before the focused window does, I do not know on what object to install it?

Comment: What you are attempting is probably not qt-related. You should rather look for symbian docs - perhaps something on event filtering (I have no idea, never wrote a single line for symbian ;)

Comment: Well thanks anyway, Symbian code would also be helpful if anyone can please help.